# MySQL, usar quantidade SUM(total) > 10 no WHERE

Tags: mysql, select, where

Tenho a seguinte consulta MYSQL:

```
SELECT SUM(A.val) AS totalvendas, B.cod AS codigo, B.nom AS Nome, B.reg AS regiao FROM venda AS A LEFT JOIN vendedor AS B ON A.ven = B.cod WHERE reg = "norte" GROUP BY A.ven ORDER BY totalvendas DESC;
```

Ela me retorna o seguinte:

```
totalvendas | codigo | Nome | regiao
-----------------------------------
144         |    1   |Sr. A | Norte
93          |   10   |Sr. J | Norte
49          |   16   |Sr. Q | Norte
42          |    6   |Sr. F | Norte
30          |    5   |Sr. E | Norte
1           |   12   |Sr. M | Norte
```

O que eu quero após o select, é fazer um novo select mas que retorne apenas os que tenham a SOMA maior que 45 por exemplo, quero apenas jogar um número neste select e poder ter o resultado apenas dos desejados.
Se por acaso eu adicionar no select acima no WHERE um:

```
AND totalvendas > 45
```

Assim:

```
SELECT SUM(A.val) AS totalvendas,B.cod AS codigo, B.nom AS Nome, B.reg AS regiao FROM venda AS A LEFT JOIN vendedor AS B ON A.ven = B.cod WHERE reg = "norte" AND totalvendas > 45 GROUP BY A.ven ORDER BY totalvendas DESC;
```

Torna-se uma consulta inválida...
Como posso resolver este problema sem ter que estocar os totais em tabelas temporárias?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cláusula 'HAVING', da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT SUM(A.val) AS totalvendas,B.cod AS codigo, B.nom AS Nome, B.reg AS regiao
FROM venda AS A LEFT JOIN vendedor AS B ON A.ven =regiao
WHERE reg = "norte"
GROUP BY regiao
HAVING totalvendas > 45
ORDER BY totalvendas DESC;
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, Obrigado mesmo!
Jóinha (Y) (+1)